# OneHotEncoding for LSTM Categorical Sequence in TensorFlow

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras, one-hot-encoding

From a set of categories labelled by numbers I am predicting the next category in the sequence. I have modeled this on a text generator (hence the random titles!).

I created a number for each category so it could be interpreted by keras and tensorflow as numerical information assigning these numbers through the enumerate function. It threw up an error suggesting I should use OneHotEncoding for outputs. I don't know how to proceed.

I have sampled what OneHotEncoding of the information would look like but I don't know how to work this into the body of the code going forward/ conversely how to change my code so that the input without OneHotEncoding works.

I don't think I understand M/c learning well enough just yet, I am teaching myself.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from numpy import argmax

import tensorflow as tf

import keras
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.models import Model

data= ['10001426', '10001426','10001426','5121550', '5431000', '10001426', '10001426', '10001466','10001426','5121550', '10001426', '10001426', '10001426','10001426','5431000', '10001426', '10001426', '10001466','10001426','5121550', '5431000', '10001426', '10001426', '10001466','10001426','5121550', '5431000', '10001426', '10001426', '10001466','10001426','5121550', '5431000', '10001426', '10001426', '10001466','10001426','5121550']
data= array(data)

chars=['10001426','5121550','5431000','10001466']
chars= array(chars)
"""
#OneHotEncode - turns the category into an encoded array
encoded = to_categorical(data)
print(encoded)
encoded2 = to_categorical(chars)
print(encoded2)

#Invert OneHotEncode

 inverted = argmax(encoded[0])
 print inverted
 inverted2 = argmax(encoded[0])
 print inverted2
"""
#Parameters
SEQ_LENGTH = 2 # Learn in steps of 2
VOCAB_SIZE = len(chars) #numer of features - how many categories of fault

#Prepare training data

ix_to_char={ix:char for ix, char in enumerate(chars)}
char_to_ix={char:ix for ix, char in enumerate(chars)}

X= np.zeros((len(data)/SEQ_LENGTH, SEQ_LENGTH, VOCAB_SIZE))
y= np.zeros((len(data)/SEQ_LENGTH, SEQ_LENGTH, VOCAB_SIZE))


for i in range((len(data)/SEQ_LENGTH)):
    if (i+1)*SEQ_LENGTH<len(data):       
       X_sequence = data[(i)*SEQ_LENGTH:(i+1)*SEQ_LENGTH]


        X_sequence_ix=[char_to_ix[value] for value in X_sequence]
        input_sequence= np.zeros((SEQ_LENGTH, VOCAB_SIZE))

        print ((i+1)*SEQ_LENGTH, len(data))
        print input_sequence

    for j in range(SEQ_LENGTH):
        input_sequence[j][X_sequence_ix[j]]=1.
    X[i]=input_sequence

    y_sequence = data[i*SEQ_LENGTH+1:(i+1)*(SEQ_LENGTH+1)]
    y_sequence_ix = [char_to_ix[value] for value in y_sequence]
    target_sequence= np.zeros((SEQ_LENGTH, VOCAB_SIZE))

    for j in range(SEQ_LENGTH):
        if (i+1)*(SEQ_LENGTH+1)<(SEQ_LENGTH):
           target_sequence[j][y_sequence_ix[j]]=1
    y[i]=target_sequence
    print y[i]


#Create the network
HIDDEN_DIM=1 
LAYER_NUM= 1

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(HIDDEN_DIM, input_shape=(None, VOCAB_SIZE), 
return_sequences=True))

for i in range(LAYER_NUM-1):
    model.add(LSTM(HIDDEN_DIM, return_sequences=True))         
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="rmsprop")


#Train the network

nb_epoch = 0
BATCH_SIZE = 5
GENERATE_LENGTH = 7

while True:
    print ('\n\n')
    model.fit(X,y,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,verbose=1, epochs=1)
    nb_epoch +=1
    generate_text(model, GENERATE_LENGTH)

    if nb_epoch %5==0:
        model.save_weights('checkpoint_{}_epoch_{}.hdf5'.format(HIDDEN_DIM, nb_epoch))

model.summary()
```

Comment: Try using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as a loss function.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot that your final layer should have an output of size `VOCAB_SIZE`. You could either do this by adding a special `Dense` layer:

```
for i in range(LAYER_NUM-1):
    model.add(LSTM(HIDDEN_DIM, return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(Dense(VOCAB_SIZE))         
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="rmsprop")
```

or by setting appropriate output from last `LSTM` layer (I will skip code for this part as it's a little bit tedious).

Comment: Thank you! Really helpful. I have addressed this now :)